# NS_OPTIONS matches

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to implement the following typedef

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS (NSInteger, MyCellCorners) {
    MyCellCornerTopLeft,
    MyCellCornerTopRight,
    MyCellCornerBottomLeft,
    MyCellCornerBottomRight,
};
```

and correctly assign a value with

```
MyCellCorners cellCorners = (MyCellCornerTopLeft | MyCellCornerTopRight);
```

when drawing my cell, how can I check which of the options match so I can correctly draw it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The correct way to check for this value is to first bitwise AND the values and then check for equality to the required value.

```
MyCellCorners cellCorners = MyCellCornerTopLeft | MyCellCornerTopRight;

if ((cellCorners & MyCellCornerTopLeft) == MyCellCornerTopLeft) {
    // top left corner set
}
```

The following reference explains why this is correct and provides other insights into enumerated types.

Reference: [checking-for-a-value-in-a-bit-mask](http://sam.dods.co/blog/2014/02/01/checking-for-a-value-in-a-bit-mask/)

Comment: pretty old question, but there are confusion in answer. For NS_Options will be enough to check
`if (cellCorners & MyCellCornerTopLeft) {`

in provided reference there are mistake, author talks about NS_Options but in example he used TransitionCurlDown which is NS_Enum.

check from answer is correct for NS_Enum, but for NS_Enum we can use simple `==` comparison.

Comment: @evfemist Using `if( myValue & comparisonValue ) { ... }` is only suitable if `comparisonValue` contains a single option, or if you just want to match *any* option within comparisonValue, which is sometimes the case. But other cases you might define an option that contains multiple options, like in OPs case maybe a `MyCellCornerTop`, which could be equal to 3 (MyCellCornerTopRight | MyCellCornerTopLeft).  If you then did `if( myCellCorners & MyCellCornerTop )`, it's going to return true if EITHER TopLeft or TopRight is included, but you might want to be checking for both, so you need the `==`

Comment: @JakeT. yes, you are right about option that contains multiple options. Didn't thought about this case, usually NS_Option doesn't have grouped options, but as we can see in `NSLayoutFormatOptions`: option value can be any.

Comment: bitwise option sets are most powerful that way. You can eliminate tons of wasted database space by storing a bunch of object configuration values in a single int instead of under individual fields.

Answer (score 55):

Use bit masking:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS (NSInteger, MyCellCorners) {
    MyCellCornerTopLeft = 1 << 0,
    MyCellCornerTopRight = 1 << 1,
    MyCellCornerBottomLeft = 1 << 2,
    MyCellCornerBottomRight = 1 << 3,
};

MyCellCorners cellCorners = MyCellCornerTopLeft | MyCellCornerTopRight;

if (cellCorners & MyCellCornerTopLeft) {
    // top left corner set
}

if (etc...) {

}
```

Comment: The `else if` should only be an `if`. Multiple options are possible.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with NSWill. I recently had a similar issue with wrong comparison.

The right if statement should be:

```
if ((cellCorners & MyCellCornerTopLeft) == MyCellCornerTopLeft){
```

Comment: You are repeating @nswill 's answer